# Brillouin scattering in multimode fibers

Tags: optics, scattering, fiber-optics, laser-cavity

Fiber ring resonators made up of single mode fibers often incorporate an optical isolator to suppress the build-up of Brillouin scattering. However, ring resonators made of multimode fibers generally do not contain an isolator.

Why is it that the adverse effects of Brillouin scattering are negligible in multimode fibers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Stimulated Brillouin scattering is propagating "backwards", hence isolator effectively kills it while allowing laser operation in main direction.
2. Multi-mode fiber lasers are typically not single-frequency, hence SBS is much less of a concern.

So, if you make single-mode fiber laser, but not single frequency, with large enough bandwidth (>>10GHz) - it would also not require special means for SBS suppression.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. But could you explain the second point a little further? Why is SBS not a major issue when you have a large bandwidth?

Comment: @Merin Because SBS has narrow gain bandwidth : "For silica fibers, the Brillouin frequency shift is of the order of 10–20 GHz, and the Brillouin gain has an intrinsic bandwidth of typically 50–100 MHz". https://www.rp-photonics.com/brillouin_scattering.html

Comment: Are you suggesting that for SBS to occur you need high powers at specific frequencies? That means that in multimode fibers the power is distributed between a larger number of frequencies, so often none of them have enough power to give rise to the counter-propagating Brillouin waves. Is that correct?

Comment: @Merin That is correct. Also, it is possible that in multimode fiber different modes will have different SBS gain profile too.